# Proof verification: A certain process of redistribution stops after a finite number of steps.

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification, alternative-proof

> **QUESTION:** There are $n\ge 3$ girls in a class sitting around a circular table, each having some apples with her. Every time the teacher notices a girl having more apples than both of her neighbours combined, the teacher takes away one apple from that girl and gives one apple each to her neighbours. Prove that, this process stops after a finite number of steps.
> (Assume that, the teacher has an abundant supply of apples.)

---

**MY ANSWER:**
We define the girls as gears. Now, let any gear which has more number of apples than it's immediate neighboring gears rotate clockwise, and consequently the neighbors rotate counterclockwise..

(Note: The gears rotate only in groups of $3$ and the rotation of any group **does not** affect the other groups)

Any clockwise rotation decreases the number of apples by $1$ and any counter rotation increases the number by $1$.

We define, a group of $3$ gears to be in a stationary state if the gear that is trapped on both the sides has **$\leq$** number of apples than the sum of its neighboring gears. In such a case, the group does not rotate, and remains stationary..

Now, firstly, since we are considering positive integers, any group must come to a stationary state after **finite** number of rotations..

Define $\Omega_k = a_{1k}+a_{2k}+a_{3k}+....+a_{nk}$ as the sum of the number of apples in any $k^{th}$ step. Here each $a_{ik}$ denotes the number of apples possessed by the $i^{th}$ girl, at the $k^{th}$ step.

Define $\Delta_k=max(a_{1k},a_{2k},.....,a_{nk})$ as the maximum number of apples possessed by some girl at any $k^{th}$ step.

Say, $\Delta_0=a_j$, for some $j\in\{1\leq{a}\leq{n}, a\in\Bbb{N}\}$ (where $\Delta_0$ represents the initial step)

Define $V(a_g)$ to be the maximum number of apples possessed by some girl, which is $\leq$ girl $g$, or in the set excluding girl $g$.

**$\color{red}{Claim :}$**$\Delta_k\leq{a_j}$, $\forall k \in \{1,2,3,......,n\}$

**$\color{red}{Proof:}$** Let us start the process with the group $(a_{j-1},a_j,a_{j+1})$..

Since, we have already proved that the number of rotations will be finite for this group to attain a stationary state. Let us say, after the $m^{th}$ step,

$a_{jm}<V(a_j)$

From this step onwards until the completion of the last step (say $p$) of this group, $\Delta_k=V(a_j)$, where $m\leq{k}\leq{p}$

And $\forall k<m$, $\Delta_k$ was clearly $=a_j$.

Therefore, we see that in the whole process the value of $\Delta$ never increases..

So, following the same pattern, we can say, for any group which attains a stationary state, the value of $\Delta$ either remains same or decreases by $1$.

$\therefore \Delta_k\leq{a_j}$, $\forall k \in \{1,2,3,......,n\}$

This completes the proof of our claim.  $\blacksquare$

Hence, we can say, $\Delta_1\geq\Delta_2\geq.......\geq\Delta_n$.

This clearly proves $\Delta$ is a non-increasing function..

But, we also observe that the value of the sum $\Omega$ increases by $1$ after every step.

$\Omega_{k}= a_{1k}+a_{2k}+.......+a_{nk}$
$\Omega_{k}<\Delta_{k}+\Delta_{k}+...... n$ times

$\implies \Omega_{k}<n.\Delta_{k}$.
$\implies \Omega_{k}<n.\Delta_{0}$

But, $\Delta_{0}$ is a constant.. $\Omega$ increases constantly by $1$.

Hence, for this inequality to hold true, $\Omega$ cannot increase indefinitely, and therefore, the process must terminate after finite number of steps...

Q.E.D.             $\square$

---

> Is my proof correct? If not, can someone please prove it in a more elegant way?

Comment: Not sure I understand the rules.  If, for each configuration $c$ we define $F(c)=\sum \max(0, a_i-(a_{i-1}+a_{i+1}))$ (with, I hope, obvious notation) doesn't the given procedure $c\mapsto c'$ lower  that function each time?  If so, then it must halt after at most $F(c)$ stages.

Comment: @lulu hats off!!.. you did in one line, what I could not in a full page!.. you are absolutely correct..

Comment: Oh, no worries.  With problems like this, it's often just a matter of thinking of the right function.  I'll post my argument below so the problem can be closed.

Comment: @lulu Yes sure.. Thank you for your help.. I will try to keep that in mind and hunt for the right functions first, than to start with proofs right away...

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: @Shaun, thank you so much for your suggestion.. since this question is already closed, I will keep that in mind for future posts.. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simpler argument:

For each configuration $c$  we define the $\textit{unfairness}$ function by $$F(c)=\sum \max(0, a_i-(a_{i-1}+a_{i+1}))$$

Here, of course, $a_i$ is the number of apples the $i^{th}$ girl currently has and the indices are handled cyclically.

Then each iteration of the "smoothing" operation lowers $F$ hence the whole thing must halt after at most $F(c)$ iterations, and we are done.

Note:  to see that one iteration of smoothing lowers $F$, let $$F_i(c)=\max(a_i-(a_{i-1}+a_{i+1}))$$ and consider one girl, $\#3$, say, who has more apples than her neighbors combined.  Then, of course, we have $F_3(c)=a_3-(a_2+a_4)>0$.  When we smooth we leave all the $a_i$ the same except that $a_3'=a_3-1$, $a_2'=a_2+1$ and $a_4'=a_4+1$.  Now we need to look at each term in the sum to see if it might have increased.  Of course $F_3(c)$ has dropped by either $1$ or $2$.  What about the other terms that may have changed?  Well, to compute $F_2(c')$ we remark that $a_3>a_2+a_4$ implies that $a_3>a_2+1$ (since each girl has some apples) so $a_3≥a_2+2$ so $a_3'=a_3-1≥a_2+1=a_2'$.  It follows that $F_2(c')=0$ so it did not increase.  The same argument applies to $F_4(c')$ and, as these are the only ones that might have increased, we are done.

Comment: Is it advisable to write $$\sum_{cyc}$$ when I am dealing with cyclic summations?

Comment: Personally, I don't think so.  I'm not sure that's a universally understood notation so you'd end up just defining the sum anyway.  But if you know your audience and you know that they are familiar with that notation, then it is an efficient way to write down what you want.

Comment: Okay.. Thanks again :)

Comment: It's not obvious to me that each step actually lowers this sum.  Would you mind elaborating?

Comment: @RobertShore  Sure, I'll edit to add more details.

Comment: @RobertShore  I've added some details.  I use the assumption that $a_i>0$ for all $i$ which I am not sure is necessary, but it did seem to arise when I was checking cases.